# How can I build the ios unity project as ios framework project?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, frameworks

I did export iOS Unity Project, and then i want to convert the project to iOS Framework Project. Because i want to make the project into SDK(.framework) for using the SDK in other normal app.

When it is built into framework project, Crash in `UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics()`.

> (crash occurred >>> il2cpp::vm:MetadataCache::Initialize())

Application project (include unity ios framework) is occurred in following function.

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
   {
      ...
      // it is occurred crash in following function. (the parameter is path of Application(.app))
      UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String]);
      ...
   }
```

It also is called `UnityInitTrampoline();` and `UnityParseCommandLine(argc, argv);` of the framework in `main.mm` of Application Project (argv parameter is path of Application(.app)).

What is the meaning of `UnityInitTrampoline();` and `UnityParseCommandLine(argc, argv);` functions?

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to "load" Unity into a normal iOS app or something?

Comment: I did export iOS Unity Project, and then i want to convert the project to iOS Framework Project. Because i want to make the project into SDK(.framework) for using the SDK in other normal app.

Comment: I don't see how that's going to work.  You cannot just repackage applications as frameworks and expect them to work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: There's a similar attempt to do just like you, but I believe it went further. Although it's not successful yet, but you might get something from this. See more info here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-anyone-else-seeing-metadatacache-initialize-crashes-sometimes-when-the-game-starts.383145/.

Comment: In short for your problem, try to make sure your `Data/` is at the right place. If you created a new target, then you need to add that into `Copy Build Resources` inside target's `Build Phases`. Then you need to change `UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String]);` into `UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics([[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[UnityRenderingView class]] bundlePath] UTF8String]);`. That will make sure it refer to the proper bundle path. But still even doing just that you will face another problem if WriteLock().

Comment: WriteLock() problem same as mine can be found [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/build-unity-app-as-framework-then-consumed-by-another-app.430068/).